# Making delta file without a Basis (Source) File?

Tags: delphi, diff, rsync, delta

(OK, don't yell at me, it's very late here :))

I'm researching delta diff tools (commandline tools or components, it doesn't matter as long as I can call them from **Delphi 2010**)

I have this project where I upload files to a server, I need to optimize upload and so it would really great if I can upload the delta file only instead of sending the new file and then comparing both old & new file versions on the server.

I read about Duplicity [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

> Duplicity is a variation on rdiff-backup that allows for backups without cooperation from 
>   the storage server, as with simple storage services like Amazon S3. It works by 
>   generating the hashes for each block in advance, encrypting them, and storing them on the 
>   server, then retrieving them when doing an incremental backup. The rest of the data is 
>   also stored encrypted for security purposes.

This got me thinking, is there a tool (or a way) to generate a patch or delta file (I'm not sure what the proper term is) based on the **new** file, **without** having access to the original file?

I mean let's say I have this file that I modified once:

```
my-data.db
[ my-data.db ] modified       --> [ delta-file-1.diff ]
```

Is there a way to construct [ delta-file-1.diff ] based on the new file **without** having access to the old file? (may be by storing some kind of a signature for the original file?)

I researched a lot this topic (rdiff, PatchAPI, ZDelta, XDelta, MSDelta, etc...) but I can't find any real-world working example on this.

These references talk about this but I wanted to hear if anyone can guide me and/or suggest better tools that answer the question that I asked above.

[Compressing a Target Without a Source File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417345.aspx#patchapi_comptarg)

[Windows Patch API: Compressing a Target Without a Basis (Source) File](http://fixunix.com/programmer/95507-windows-patch-api-compressing-target-without-basis-source-file.html)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to get the difference between A and B, without knowing A?

Comment: @Kay: Point well taken, I'd rather say I'd like to get the difference between A and B, with only the "signature" of A in hand (series of hashes identifying A may be?)...there's really no shame in asking, you know

Comment: @Ken: please read my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441801/making-delta-file-without-a-basis-source-file#comment12047688_9442106), indeed there's a way to do that, the only thing left to know is which tool is the best (I could only find one software that does this: rdiff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested: there's [rdiff](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/rdiff.html) which does have a windows port and can be launched from Delphi, and [librsync](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/) which is, if I understood correctly, the engine behind rdiff.

Both require signature of the old file (which is **much** smaller than the file itself) and the complete new file.

*Reverse delta* can be done to allow getting the new file from the old one.

Answer (score 1):

When you only append to a file or edit in blocks of known size (most likely not possible for text files), I guess hashing would be feasible. See eMule's AICH ([eMule wiki](http://emule-project.net/home/perl/help.cgi?l=1&topic_id=589&rm=show_topic)/[aMule wiki](http://wiki.amule.org/index.php/AICH)).

Essentially you split a file into blocks of size N, and calculate the hash code of each block. Then you calculate a "super hash" out of M blocks. With that approach you could track down changed blocks without having to transfer much metadata.

Otherwise: You cannot create the whole file out of a diff without knowing the base the diff was taken of. Neither can you create a diff without knowing the base.

Comment: Thank you, yes! This is kind of what I had in mind (hash for each slice/bloc). However, I was rather skeptical but your idea of super hashes is very interesting and may very well do the trick...I'm going to take a look at it, thanks!

Comment: @Gdhami `rsync` works by calculating hashes of blocks (so it only has to send differences of blocks that actually differ in stead of sending the complete diff between A and B over the line). But it still needs the complete A and complete B.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: I was kind of hoping to find some "magical" way to achieve this. Thank you guys for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Gdhami you are most welcome, I'm glad you found our help of use.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not get the difference from A and B without a way to get A and B.

You could reconstruct A from older versions of A and applying the differences.

The signature of A won't cut it.

Comment: In the MSDN link mentioned in my question, I found this: "Compressing a Target Without a Source File 
Describes how the API functions can be used to create a delta without referencing a source file."

Comment: I don't have much faith in MS, but unless I misread this, it seems somehow possible(?)

Comment: Regardless of faith in MS, I think you misread the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417345.aspx#patchapi_comptarg) you mentioned in your edited question. The link indicates `If a CreatePatch function is called and the source file is specified as NULL or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, the output will be a compressed representation of the target file.` which means that the delta will only describe the target B, not the difference between the source A and the target B.

Comment: OK, after some research, I finally decided to un-accept the answer. First there's dropbox which obviously **does** implement something like this and second, patch without having both files at the same machine (ie. using a file signature) has **already** been implemented in [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/node2.html) (well, kind of) and in [rdiff](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/rdiff.html)